# HTML , Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have some text shown by the label in HTML. This label must get its text from a Javascript function when the page is loaded or reloaded. How can I achieve this? The text will be dynamic.

```
<label id="MyLabel"></label>


<script type="text/javascript">
labelFunc(){
            document.getElementById("MyLabel").innerHTML='<?php echo $_SESSION["SomeSession"];?>';
}
</script>
```

The Label '**MyLabel**' should get its text from the '**labelFunc()**' javascript function.

Comment: So define the function properly and call it onload....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is just fine as it is, you just need to make sure the page is loaded before the JS is executed. do that by either putting your JS at the bottom, or calling it when the page is loaded.

```
<body onload="labelFunc();">
```

also, you need the word "function"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function labelFunc(){
            document.getElementById("MyLabel").innerHTML='<?php echo $_SESSION["SomeSession"];?>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: @AjinkyaTalele - Great! If this answered your question, please hit the check mark by the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You've created the `labelFunc` function, but never called it, so it never gets executed. Also, your function declaration syntax is incorrect - you need to put `function` before you write your function.

To update your existing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function labelFunc(){
            document.getElementById("MyLabel").innerHTML='<?php echo $_SESSION["SomeSession"];?>';
}
labelFunc();
</script>
```

If you never need to call that function again, then using a function would be unnecessary - you could simply just put it the code you need to run on its own inside the script tag:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("MyLabel").innerHTML='<?php echo $_SESSION["SomeSession"];?>';
</script>
```